# Log method calls while running program

Tags: java, emf

I am working with EMF (Eclipse Modeling Framework) and have an automatic generated context menu with some actions. When I execute an action over the context menu in the program I have no idea which method in which class is called in the source code.

Is there a way that I can find out which method is called in which class, when I am running the program. I would set a breakpoint for debugging but I don't know where to set.

Suppose I have totaly no idea where to set the first breakpoint - isn't there something like a log file for all method which where called during running the application?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the deepest point you **know** you will pass which has a connection to the action you performed. From there on you can step into, out and over your code.

Comment: And when I have totaly no clue where to set the first breakpoint? Maybe there is something like a log file for called methods during running the application

Comment: You can use AspectJ to log every method invocation made by your code. Doing so is not trivial. There are plenty of examples on the web, search using keywords: AspectJ, Logging. I refer to the web as an answer because I simply can not explain write an 'answer' on how to do this in such a way that you can adjust it to your scenario... books have been written on this subject.

Comment: Thanks for making an effort to help me with my question!!

Answer (score 0):

You could set your breakpoint on the class (instead of any specific method or line).